# razor foreach using ICollection

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am using razor to display a list of authors, as you can see uno "MyClass" can have many authors.

```
   public class MyClass
{   
    [Key]
    public int MyClassId{ get; set; }
    //more properties
    /*****One measure has many authors*****/
    public virtual ICollection<Author> Authors { get; set; }

}
public class Author
{
    [Key]
    public int AuthorId { get; set; }

    public virtual Measure Measure { get; set; }

    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

I want to display in a foreach loop FirstName and LastName

```
  @foreach (var item in Model.Authors)
                {
                   @item.FirstName+" " + @item.LastName
                 }
```

But it seems I am not using the correct sintax, how do I display firstname and lastname?

Thanks

Comment: What is not working? What errors are you getting? What is actually happening (the code you have shown is fine assuming the collection contains items)

Comment: thanks for writing, for some reason, I am not getting the name and LasName. When render the view, is empty the zone where it is suposed to be the name and lastname

Comment: The I can only assume that those properties do not have a value when you send the model to the view. Debug your code!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure these steps are done:

1) Pass the model to the view (obviously WITH data in it)

```
var myModel = //some object of your MyClass;
return View(myModel);
```

2) add `@model MyClass`to the top of your View to receive the model

3) the loop should look like this:

```
@foreach (var item in Model.Authors.ToList())
{
   <p>
      @Html.Raw(item.FirstName + " " + item.LastName)
   </p>
}
```

*EDIT*:  .ToList() is probably necessary because Authors is of Type  `ICollection`

Comment: @edMundo or just define Authors as List<Author> instead of ICollection<Author>

Answer (score 0):

> @item.FirstName+" " + @item.LastName

at runtime, error should be thrown, correct syntax:

Option 1:

```
@foreach (var item in Model.Authors)
{
  @item.FirstName @item.LastName
}
```

Option 2:

```
@foreach (var item in Model.Authors)
{
   string contactenated = item.FirstName + " " + item.LastName;
   @contactenated
}
```